# Fastest way to reverse a string in python

Tags: python, string, performance

I was able to come up with two different ways to reverse a string in Python.

Common sense dictates that code with more lines should run slower. I reversed a the string in two ways.

Implementation 1:

```
"".join(reversed(map(lambda x:x,st)))
```

Implementation 2:

```
st[::-1]
```

These have similar performance. Even for a 20000-character string, the difference is less than one millisecond.

I think the first one should be a slower approach because it performs 3x more operations.

Why am I not seeing a performance difference?

Comment: How did you time these two? I get reasonable results for a string with 20,000 characters: https://i.imgur.com/DhKaxhR.png

Comment: Any reason why you did not use: `''.join(reversed(st))` in the first case?

Comment: i used time.now() in start of code and time.now() at the end of it to benchmark.

@Cyb3rFly3r: It was not about coming up with an efficient algo but to see which one of these two would be faster
But yeah `''.join(reversed(st))` did not corss my mind

Answer (score 24):

I see a difference.

First of all, what is up with `map(lambda x: x, st)`?  What is the purpose?

Use the `timeit` module to test your code:

```
$ python -m timeit '"".join(reversed("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.586 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit '"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[::-1]'           
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0715 usec per loop
```

As you can see, the slice is ~8x faster on my machine for this particular input.  It's also more concise.

Comment: That is more in line with my expectation; it is known in the Python community that method 2 is faster than all others for reversing strings.

Comment: "".join is really inefficient...opposed to just reversing, this one does multiple actions.

Comment: That's not 20000 long (which is what the question talked about).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Do you think that the difference in length makes an important difference here? The reason I chose a longer string is just so that it would be easier to measure. I think it would be hard to make the case that the results from longer strings do not generalize to results from shorter strings.

Comment: Well, they talked about length 20000, and their question is *"Why am I not seeing a performance difference?"*. And you're not looking at what they were looking at. I find that improper and not satisfactorily answering the question. It *could* make a difference. In general it's not unusual that different solutions are faster for different sizes. (Your comment also has it backwards, you chose a much *shorter* string.) ...

Comment: ... Also, what *really* should've happened is someone requesting *"What exactly **are** you seeing, and exactly how did you measure?"* and then nobody should've answered before they show that. Because the *real* answer to their question most certainly is *"Because you measured badly"*. And for that, their measuring and results need to be shown.

Comment: @KellyBundy: You say that the real answer “most certainly” is "Because you measured badly", but I don’t see a justification for that—can you justify that, or is it guesswork on your part? Where reasonable, I generally prefer to write an answer that is clear, factual and helpful.

Comment: These comments do not improve the answer so I won’t incorporate them.

Comment: You might call it an educated guess, based on what I know about how Python works and my experience with maybe thousands of benchmarks I've written myself or seen from others (including testing this with short and long strings). Do you actually doubt it? To be clear: "Because you measured badly" of course only described the essence of the answer. The actual answer would of course explain *why/how* their measurement was bad. I can't tell why/how now, because I can't see how they measured. They mentioned a little bit, but it's lacking details, and time.now as far as I can tell never even existed.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Right, “because you measured badly” is the essence of your answer, but because you don’t actually know how the OP measured, you can’t explain why the measurements are wrong, and so you have to add excuses and guesswork to your answer—and that’s going to make it harder to write an answer which is clear and direct. Maybe you should write your own answer—it sounds like you have opinions about how the answer to this question should be written, but it doesn’t sound like you have actionable suggestions which improve this answer.

Comment: *"you have to add excuses and guesswork to your answer"* No, I don't even have to answer at all. I'm perfectly happy waiting for question authors to provide all needed information before writing an answer. *"it doesn’t sound like you have actionable suggestions which improve this answer"* - Measuring with their length instead of a very different one is an actionable suggestion which would improve this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254253/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-kelly-bundy).

Answer (score 1):

```
s=input("enter string")
print(s[::-1])
```

Comment: this just add one option from the question to the answer, the question need the compare for two options.