# Sum of Strings as Numbers

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5324945e2ece5e1f32000370/train/python) exercise from Codewars.

Description:

Given the string representations of two integers, return the string representation of the sum of those integers.
For example: sumStrings('1','2') // => '3'
A string representation of an integer will contain no characters besides the ten numerals "0" to "9".
I have removed the use of BigInteger and BigDecimal in java
Python: your solution need to work with huge numbers (about a milion digits), converting to int will not work.

In Python, all my test cases are OK, but the Execution Timed Out is still showing up. Any hints to make it work, please? What other approach could i adopt?
My current code is down below.
Really appreciate any help!!

```py
def sum_strings(x, y):
      
    if x == '' and y == '':
        return '0'
    
    if x == '0' and y == '0':
        return '0'
    
    if x == '' and y == '0' or x == '0' and y == '':
        return '0'
    
    listaX = list(x)
    listaY = list(y)

    if len(listaX) - len(listaY) > 0:       
        while len(listaY) < len(listaX):
            listaY.insert(0, '0')
    if len(listaY) - len(listaX) > 0:       
        while len(listaY) > len(listaX):
            listaX.insert(0, '0')

    for i in range(0, len(listaX)):        
        listaX[i] = int(listaX[i])
        listaY[i] = int(listaY[i])

    listaSomas = []
    quociente = 0

    for i in range(len(listaX) - 1, -1, -1):
        soma = listaX[i] + listaY[i] + quociente
        if soma > 9 and i > 0:
            quociente = soma // 10
            listaSomas.insert(0, soma % 10)
        elif soma > 9 and i == 0:
            quociente = soma // 10
            listaSomas.insert(0, soma % 10)
            listaSomas.insert(0, quociente)
        elif soma <= 9:
            listaSomas.insert(0, soma)
            quociente = 0
            
    if listaSomas[0] == 0:                  
        listaSomas.remove(listaSomas[0])
            
    for i in range(0, len(listaSomas)):
        listaSomas[i] = str(listaSomas[i])
    listaSomas = ''.join(listaSomas)
    
    return listaSomas

#MAIN
print(sum_strings('123', '456'))
```

Comment: Copying to a different container. Inserting at the front, converting to different types. These might be costly operations on a really big string. Can you use reversed to get iterators, combine them with itertools.zip_longest(fillvalue='0') have a function for basic arithmetic on single digits, and then reverse it again for output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code times out because of expensive operations, as I mentioned in my original comment. The main problem is inserting at the start of a list. Look up insert vs append for strings and lists here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

As you can see here, appending to a list or string is O(1) but inserting is O(n) because you have to move the rest of the list around. You do this for every digit, so you have O(n^2) complexity just to store the output.

Instead of the expensive insert-at-front operation, store the results with the much more efficient append operation. Once that's all done, simply reverse the output. String and list support efficient reversal.

[What is the time complexity of Python List Reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606159/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-python-list-reverse)

Since we want to iterate, it makes no sense to write your loops with extra code to pad the lengths. It's already done for you in itertools.

I additionally perform my digit math with ord and chr, although that's a relatively minor time saver.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

zero = ord('0')
nine = ord('9')

def sum_digits(x, y, carry):
    answer = ord(x) + ord(y) - zero
    if carry:
        answer += 1
        carry = False
    if answer > nine:
        carry = True
        answer = answer - 10
    return chr(answer), carry

def sum_strings(x, y):
    answer = ''
    carry = False
    for a, b in zip_longest(reversed(x), reversed(y), fillvalue='0'):
        c, carry = sum_digits(a, b, carry)
        answer += c
    if carry:
        answer += '1'
    answer = answer.rstrip('0')
    if not answer:
        return '0'
    return ''.join(reversed(answer))
```

Comment: I was going to leave it at my initial comment, but everyone else posted afterwards, so I thought I'd join in. I wanted to emphasize using iterators and you can see mine is faster on the testing link in OP.

Comment: It's weird that this site gave a better result with join reversed for the final return. I thought [::-1] would be faster on my local timeit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949665/fastest-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-python It must be because iterators handle large inputs better.

Comment: GOT IT! Thank You so much, Kenny! Such a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I saw that link and it clearly says : *Python: your solution need to work with huge numbers (about a milion digits), converting to int will not work.*

Some improvements I can think of are:

a) Don't insert and remove for each digit. Just append to an resultant list.

b) You don't need to append 0s before processing your strings.

A quick way to code it correctly and this got *accepted*:

```py
    def sumdigits(c, a=0, b=0):
        s = a + b + c
        if s >= 10:
            c = s // 10
            s = s % 10
        else:
            c = 0
        return s, c
    
    def sum_strings(x, y):
        i = len(x)
        j = len(y)
        c = 0
        out = []
        while i > 0 and j > 0:
            s, c = sumdigits(c, int(x[i-1]), int(y[j-1]))
            out.append(s)
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        
        
        while i > 0:
            s, c = sumdigits(c, int(x[i-1]))
            out.append(s)
            i -= 1
        
           
        while j > 0:
            s, c = sumdigits(c, int(y[j-1]))
            out.append(s)
            j -= 1
        
        
        if c > 0:
            out.append(c)
            
        out = ''.join([str(n) for n in reversed(out)]).lstrip("0")
        
        if out:
            return out
            
        return "0"
```

Comment: Logically, OP's approach is the same. This doesn't help in finding out why his submission did not work.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur OP's code is doing unnecessary operations which I mentioned in the answer which explains why it didn't get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

One loop should be enough, in order to sum up each digit of both numbers:

```
def sum_strings(x, y):
    # remove whitespaces from x and y
    x,y = map(str.strip, (x,y))

    # skip useless inputs
    if (x == '0' and y =='0') or (x == '' and y == ''):
        return "0"
    
    # determine max string, so we could fill the smaller one with leading 0s
    maxLen = max(len(x), len(y))

    # pad both numbers with 0s and reverse them, so we can sum the digits up
    x = x.zfill(maxLen)[::-1]
    y = y.zfill(maxLen)[::-1]

    r = []
    carryover = 0

    # sum both digits and keep the carryover!
    for i  in range(maxLen):
        carryover, res = str(int(x[i]) + int(y[i]) + int(carryover)).zfill(2)
        r.append(res)
        # add the carryover for the last digit as is!
        if i == maxLen-1:
            r.append(carryover)
    r = "".join(r)[::-1].lstrip("0")
    return r if r else "0"
```

Out:

```
print(sum_strings('19', '12'))
>> 31
```

Comment: Very clever solution! I'll solve the kata again, but now based on your code. Thank you so much, Maurice!

Answer (score 0):

Your code times out because `list.insert(0...` is slow.  When you insert at the beginning, all the other elements need to be move up one index.

Use `.append(...)` instead, and reverse the list when you're done.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for the insight, Matt! Really helpful.